# Unneeded prompts from Google Identity Services

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-identity

I'm converting my web app to use Google Identity Services, and am using the token model as illustrated at [Token Model example](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gapi-asyncawait).  For the token client I've specified the prompt property as an empty string, which indicates that the user will be presented with authentication and consent screens only on first access.  But on all subsequent accesses, I see a popup flash on the screen briefly and then disappear, without any response from me.  I even tried changing the prompt property to 'none' but the transient popups still appear.  Is there something I need to do to prevent this? Could it be that GIS is presenting the popup for auth/consent but then realizes it's not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

A popup is now required to obtain an access token for browser based apps, what you're seeing is a short-lived non-interactive popup used to fetch the access token.

This behavior is a result of browser policy updates to permitted actions for cross-origin iframes, and to more securely handle OAuth credentials by preventing open redirects.

While I believe what you're asking is if all user visible dialogs can be suppressed (the answer is no), replacing the flashing popup with an explicit prompt may be a better overall user experience. You can do this by setting `prompt` to `select_account`. It comes down to a choice between a short lived non-interactive prompt that may raise questions of "what did I just see?" versus an interactive prompt that adds a step to the end-to-end flow.

The other alternative is to move to a server based flow [authorization code](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model) flow which offers the most security and lowest UX friction. However, this is not an option for SPAs due to the requirement for a back-end server.